# Bridge Rectifier Network with three multimeters set to DC

Tags: transformer, rectifier

[image]

**1. Is the transformer functioning properly according to the reading of DMM1 (115-V rms)?**

In my opinion, the transformer must be working fine in this case. The turns ratio is n=1 (1:1); therefore, it should receive the same rms voltage, right? For me, that is a tricky question.

**2. Does DMM2 have the right reading?**

Yes. Theoretical computation proves it: $$V_{dc}=\frac{2(115)\sqrt{2}}{\pi }=103.5363764$$

**3. The reading of DMM3 is 0-V. Where could be the fault in the circuit?**

I think that DMM3, being set to DC voltage, has no reading due to the smoothing action of the capacitor. Am I correct?

Comment: This is not Chegg, and this question was asked earlier today.

Comment: Whatever this Chegg is, they appear to have some stuff wrong.  To get help with school questions on stack exchange you have to show personal effort.  DC on the output of a transformer simply makes no sense.  I'm unaware of a way that you could break a transformer that would cause it to turn into a rectifier and no DC source is applied to that part of the circuit.  You also need an AC multimeter reading to confirm that the transformer has no AC output, which is a better way to presume it's toast.

Comment: It's also reasonable to assume the meter is actually set to AC, in fact that's more plausible than a rectifying transformer, and easier to check than the other possibility, which is a DC source in the circuit in real life that is not shown in the diagram.  For part 2 I haven't confirmed your calculation, so check your formula and run it again if necessary, but if you have exactly the voltage you should based on 115vAC, this would lean towards dmm1 being set to AC, since if the rectifier input was DC you'd get a different number, same if it was 115VAC with a DC component.

Comment: For part 3 a random guess doesn't count as effort, although you should review what a DC multimeter does and what a capacitor does.  You have their relationship backwards.  You can verify chegg's answer easily enough but there's another possible answer, equally likely.  What do you think the purpose of Rsurge is?  My best guess is it limits surge currents charging the cap with resistance, but sometimes in a spot like that you see a fusible resistor.  That's enough hint you should be able to figure out why else there could be 0V on that node.

Comment: @KH, the DC multimeter measures the average value of the full-wave rectified voltage.

Comment: You should also look up what a DC meter reads when you connect it to an AC voltage.  true DC voltage is constant.   So the smoothing action of the capacitor, does that make the signal more dc like or less dc like?  If a DC meter reads specifically DC voltage, is that after capacitor output the type of voltage it's designed to measure?

Comment: it doesn't make any sense unless you assumne that DMM1 is in AC mode, then the readings can be explained by a single fault in one of the parts.

Comment: @KH Chegg is a company that makes money by helping students cheat on their homework and exams. Judging by this question, EE.SE will have the same role soon.

Comment: Removing all the references to Chegg, as you have done in your recent edits, does not change the fact that this is a homework and/or test problem.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I didn't know that about Chegg.  That's yucky.  That's why I didn't actually write an answer and challenged OP to participate and show effort and gave a way of thinking rather than a concrete answer to see if he was lazy or just didn't know how to think.  This question is bad and should be deleted or improved or answers should not have been given yet.  An interesting point has been brought up about the question in the question.  It is bad(requires contradiction of a given) in a sense, but it reminds the student to question the authority of information.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Reading how close I got him to a solution here, I'd say I did go a bit far without more engagement though, but I'm hoping to find the nice balance of crumbs to get them started so that students hopefully fix bad questions more often instead of just losing interest.  There are periodic surges of potentially fun questions or with interesting twists, and not being an engineer like a lot of people here, I often find school questions valuable reminders.  If it can be fixed, this is a nice question because as an electrician or hobbyist if you don't question givens you could die.

Comment: On the other hand, OP's participation was inadequate, so if the question dies so be it.

Answer (score -1):

Where's the fault? well ASSUMING that the voltmeters are functioning correctly.

the 115V AC must have a very low frequency, less than 1Hz, given that, the 115V reading on the first multimeter is possible, (this would typically require a house-sized transformier at such a low frequency)

There's 8V dropped across D1 and D2 so either they're selenium rectifiers (or something equally cruddy) or one of them has failed partially open.

there's no voltage at the output:

either that open spot means something or Rsurge has failed open.

If DMM1 one is actually in an AC-sensing mode it gets easier.

> Is the transformer functioning properly according to the reading of DMM1 (115-V rms)?

if it's reading RMS it's not in DC mode.

115V out of a 1:1 transformer is better than expected, the 100uF suggests a fairly small transformer and I would have expected a lower "K" than 0.995. but assuming an ideal 1:1 transformer that's ok.

In a working circuit meter 2 should read higher than 115V because of charge held in C1. instead it's reading 103  which is near the average magnitude of 115RMS(sine) assuming the rectifier is ideal - given the ideal transformer, the ideal diodes are less surprising

So C1 is not working.

given that DMM3 reads 0 the most likely culprit is Rsurge. if that's open-circuit then C1 won't get any of the rectified voltage and explaining the low reading on DMM2

Given that the question is flawed I would expect everyone attempting it and giving any answer or showing any working to get full marks.

Answer (score -3):

1. It would be correct if it was an AC DMM. As the comment stated, it's difficult to find a scenario where a transformer would breakdown and have a DC offset. It might be the case if there is a breakdown of the diode rectifier and one of the waves (negative or positive) is shorted but that more likely would make smoke.
2. The correct formula is 2 is [VP = VRMS × √2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square#:%7E:text=Peak%20values%20can%20be%20calculated,this%2C%20is%20about%20340%20volts.) = 162VDC minus the diode drop ~2 x 1V => ~160V
3. In the real world I would check first whether C or Rl are shorted or Rsurge open, perhaps the DMM is set to AC.